# core plot, uipinchgesture handle end state

Tags: core-plot, pinch

I need to handle the end of pinch gesture, but I don't find away to do it, I try hostingView.gestureRecognizers but after this there isn't a uipinchgesture for get the state of gesture.

This method

```
- (BOOL) plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldScaleBy:(CGFloat)interactionScale aboutPoint:(CGPoint)interactionPoint {

return YES
}
```

"handle" the pinch gesture continuously and here I can change the graph axis but i need to get the end of pinch for reload data.

I try to add a uipinchgesture to hostingView but after this I can hold the state end but the zoom don't work!

Answer (score 1):

As long as `allowPinchScaling` is `YES`, the hosting view will have a pinch gesture recognizer which will be in the `gestureRecognizers` array. Add yourself as a target so you get notified of changes. Monitor the `state` of the recognizer in your action method. The pinch gesture is complete when the state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` or `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled`.

Comment: How can I Add target to this gesture?and if I add a target I lost the zoom?I try something like this: for (UIGestureRecognizer *gest in hostingView.gestureRecognizers) {if ([gest isMemberOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]]) { NSLog(@"pinch"); [gest addTarget:self action:@selector(notifica)];}} but nothing!

Comment: ok, I forgot to add UIGesture delegate, but now if I add: - (IBAction)handlePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender the zoom not work!